# 2 column images list (figure and figcaption)

Tags: css, figure

I am trying to put the images side by side with captions.

That works out of the box by default doing the following:

```
<figure>
<img src="1.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 1">
<img src="2.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 2">
<img src="3.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 3">
<img src="4.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 4">
</figure>
```

I get the list of images side by side depending if my width allows it. I get what i want. is such 2 columns of images:

```
Image 1 Image 2
Image 3 Image 4
```

Now if i add figcaption as following:

```
<figure>
<img src="1.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 1">
<figcaption>caption 1</figcaption>
<img src="2.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 2">
<figcaption>caption 2</figcaption>
<img src="3.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 3">
<figcaption>caption 3</figcaption>
<img src="4.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 4">
<figcaption>capton 4</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Everything looks like this:

```
Image 1
caption 1 
Image 2 
caption 2 
Image 3  
caption 3 
Image 4
caption 4
```

I also was playing with lists and hierarchy and css.

The question is how can i make the following ?

```
Image 1 Image 2 
caption 1 caption 2 
image 3 Image 4   
caption 3 caption 4
```

Many Thanks,
Karolis

Comment: HTML5 Doctor says only 1 figcaption is allowed within a figure:  http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

Comment: ok thanks, but my goal is the last point, how to make 2 columns with <figure> and <figcaption> and css ?

Comment: Use "div" : http://jsfiddle.net/ZksyN/

Comment: thanks a lot! but in my case i have to use width: 1oo% instead of width: 320px, because otherwise everything is messing up, but in this case ordering is again only one by one, and not side by side :/ - can i use something with display: block or so ?

Comment: Nowhere did you specify anything being `width: 100%`.  These are important details that need to provided when you ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to fix your mark-up (only 1 figcaption allowed per figure).  Then we need to add some sort of container element.  I chose aside as my container, but it can be any block level element that feels appropriate (div, section, etc.):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZksyN/2/

```
<aside class="figures">
<figure>
<img src="1.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 1">
<figcaption>caption 1</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
<img src="2.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 2">
<figcaption>caption 2</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
<img src="3.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 3">
<figcaption>caption 3</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
<img src="4.jpg" width=320 height=240 alt="Image 4">
<figcaption>capton 4</figcaption>
</figure>
</aside>
```

Just enough CSS here to get the elements to appear inline.  You'll probably want to reduce the left/right margins on `figure`.  I've also left off any sort of restrictions on how many columns must appear, so it is responsive by default (narrow devices will get 1 column, extra wide devices could get 3 or 4 columns if they'll fit).  If you want to add a hard upper limit on the number of columns, add a max-width to `aside.figures` equal to (image width + side margins) * number of columns.

```
aside.figures {
    overflow: hidden; /* only needed if floating the child elements instead of using inline-block */
}

aside.figures figure {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much this is exactly what i was looking for :) simple, short and works!